# How to remove burger from appbar in card

Tags: widget, flutter, appbar

I have a Scaffold, which needs a drawer, so my main AppBar shows correctly the burger icon. In my body of the Scaffold, I want to show a list of Cards with a PopupMenu.

My first idea was to use an AppBar, because I also needed the title. But as you can see in my screenshot, the AppBar also renders the drawer icon.

How can I remove the drawer icon from my Card AppBars?

[image: cards with appbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `automaticallyImplyLeading` to false

```
new AppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
)
```